# Vagrant is upgrading some internal state for the latest version

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I am trying to create *vagrant* but I got below warning in terminal.

> Vagrant is upgrading some internal state for the latest version.
>   Please do not quit Vagrant at this time. While upgrading, Vagrant
>   will need to copy all your boxes, so it will use a considerable
>   amount of disk space. After it is done upgrading, the temporary disk
>   space will be freed.

Can anybody help me

Answer (score 2):

You used a older version of Vagrant (before 1.5 version) and made an upgrade to vagrant greater than 1.5 version. Vagrant 1.5 had introduced the [box 2.0 format](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-5-boxes-2-0.html) and because of that had to make the upgrade of your local boxes. This is a one time operation and you will not see this message next time you run vagrant.

Also if you did upgrade vagrant to 1.5.3+ version you should have had [a message to give you possibility to quit](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/e748aadf4f01a9227a08b85ee5b61fa217485674)

Comment: i have used vagrant 1.8